# how to run rspec with no observers in rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec

I have a rails3 app that has some observers. I can't for the life of me figure out how to turn these off for my rspec tests!

Answer (score 30):

[no_peeping_toms](https://github.com/patmaddox/no-peeping-toms) will output deprecation warnings when used with Rails 3.1+. It currently has [7 pull requests](https://github.com/patmaddox/no-peeping-toms/pulls) open to remove these deprecation warnings, however the [gem is not necessary with Rails 3.1+](https://github.com/patmaddox/no-peeping-toms/pull/14#issuecomment-4860568). Rails 3.1 added to ActiveModel (and therefore ActiveRecord) the ability to enable and [disable](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/ObserverArray.html#method-i-disable) observers.

You can put the following line in spec_helper to turn off all observers on all ActiveRecord-descendant models:

```
# spec/spec_helper.rb
...
RSpec.configure do |config|
  ...
  config.before do
    ...
    ActiveRecord::Base.observers.disable :all # <-- Turn 'em all off!
  end
end
```

You can turn them back on selectively to test their behavior by wrapping actions in your specs with the [enable](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/ObserverArray.html#method-i-enable) method.

```
# spec/models/foo_observer_spec.rb
describe FooObserver do
  subject { FooObserver.instance }

  it 'notices when new Foos are created' do
    subject.should_receive(:after_create)

    Foo.observers.enable :foo_observer do # <- Turn FooObserver on
      Foo.create('my new foo')
    end                                   # <- ... and then back off
  end
end
```

Answer (score 5):

Two options might be:

1. [No peeping toms](https://github.com/patmaddox/no-peeping-toms)
2. Add the following to your test.rb environment:
   `config.active_record.observers = []`