# How to prevent state_machine from executing when creating a model with FactoryGirl in Rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, rspec2, factory-bot, rspec-rails

It seems to me that if I use FactoryGirl to create a model whose states are handle using the state_machine gem, then state_machine will then trigger.

```
FactoryGirl.create(:order)
```

How can I prevent that?

Answer (score 0):

In fact I traced the issue to rspec not running without the observers: see [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3961880/how-to-run-rspec-with-no-observers-in-rails-3)

Answer (score 0):

If your state machine is trigger by AR call back you try skipping the callbacks using something described below:
[How to skip ActiveRecord callbacks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1342761/how-to-skip-activerecord-callbacks)

And there is also a [gem](https://github.com/wireframe/callback_skipper) which makes this work conveniently. ( I suspect the state_machine might be using callback hooks make the state changes as well).